# RedHat Openshift Service on ROSA (Cluster listing Programatically)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, openshift, redhat

If we use RedhatOpenshift Service on AWS and create a cluster which is visible on RedHat console, how can we get List of ROSA Cluster programatically in Java? Just like for KES cluster list, where we have the AWS EKS sdk which provides the API
`listClustersResult = eksClient.listClusters(listClustersRequest);`

Similarly we need to list clusters programatically.

Tried finding RedHat API https://docs.openshift.com/rosa/welcome/index.html but did not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's simple and difficult. Because you should read and understand the "rosa list cluster" implementation and translate it with Java by yourself.

https://github.com/openshift/rosa/blob/master/cmd/list/cluster/cmd.go

Comment: Ok. So it means unlike AWS SDK we do not have Any Java SDK readily available for Rosa and we have to make use of rosa cli list cluster command to run as a shell command in java and transform response?

Comment: AFAIK, I did not heard oriented API for Java. But you can utilize usual REST API based on api.opneshift.com regardless of language dependency. Unfortunately, I have no information about the API for specific feature implementation for me... So you need to read the "rosa list cluster" codes I mentioned for implementation as Java.